# grid one big box on left side and others on right side of him using GRID

Tags: css, css-grid

I am wondering how to make boxes like on picture: [image]

On the left main box, on the right h1 and smaller boxes. I have to use GRID (display: grid etc, not col-2 ..). Is it possible?

Comment: please consider reading the tag description before using them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.rectangle, .square {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rectangle {
  grid-row-start: span 3;
}

.square {
  height: 200px;
}

h1 {
  grid-column-start: span 4;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="rectangle">
  </div>
  
  <h1>Title</h1>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
  </div>
</div>
```